# Delphi Service to Listen to TCP or UDP

Tags: delphi, windows-services, udp, delphi-xe3

Reading this question:
[Delphi Windows Service Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537267/delphi-windows-service-design/10538102#10538102), I saw that most designer use this code below in the `OnExecute` of the `TService` or in the `TThread` method, in order to keep service alive.

```
while not Terminated do
begin
  // do something
end;
```

But what if I need (and I do) to create a service to respond (using Indy) to messages sent by the main application in order to send back some authentication data, what do I do with this code, ignore it or put some `Sleep()` in it?

Comment: You don't need to implement the `OnExecute` event method of the `TService` class. It's optional.

Comment: TLama is right. It is best not to use the `OnExecute` event at all. You should move that logic to a separate worker thread that is started in the `OnStart` event and terminated in the `OnStop` event. If `OnExecute` is not assigned at all, `TService` will respond to SCM requests for you. But if `OnExecute` is assigned, you are responsible for calling `ServiceThread.ProcessRequests()` manually, and the service will stop itself when `OnExecute` exits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indy's `TIdTCPServer` and `TIdUDPServer` components are multi-threaded, so you don't really need to use the `TService.OnExecute` event at all.  You could just activate them in the `TService.OnStart` event and deactivate them in the `TService.OnStop` event, and then assign handlers to the `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` and `TIdUDPServer.OnUDPRead` events as needed.  Both events are already looped for you, so you don't need a `while not Terminated` loop in them.  Just read/process one request as needed, then exit, and wait for the next event to repeat.  Let the server handle any exceptions that are raised.  And keep in mind that `TIdUDPServer` has a `ThreadedEvent` property that is False by default, so you should set it to True inside a service.

Comment: Should I use the `AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;` on the UDPRead to point to another function to be started instead of coding inside the UDPRead? What is the difference?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. The `AThread` parameter merely specifies which internal thread is receiving the data. It is primarily only useful for accessing the `TIdUDPListenerThread.Server` and `TIdUDPListenerThread.Data` properties. The `ABinding` parameter specifies the `TIdUDPServer.Binding` socket that received the data, so you can get Peer info from it, and send replies back on the same socket. Whether you decide to code your logic inside the `OnUDPRead` event handler directly or delegate to another function is up to you.