# Running Service Continuously - Delphi

Tags: delphi

My service does not seem to continuously run.

```
procedure TService1.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
While not Terminated do
  ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True);
end;
```

This is what I currently have that is suppose to be keeping the service running, but it does not do so.

Comment: Hi Jayden, Don't use the serviceexecute event but start your own thread from onstart and stop it in onstop events. More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537267/delphi-windows-service-design/10538102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit of code only runs when the service is started from the Windows Service Manager. Once you have your service `.exe` file, use a command prompt to start it with the `/install` command line argument, and use `net start <your-service-name>` or the Service Management dailog from the Administrative Tools from the Start Menu or Control Panel to start the service.

If you want to run the service *in* the Delphi debugger, start Delphi with administrative privileges and attach to the running process. But it's more advisable to have all logic in separate units, and have a separate version of the project as a 'plain exe' the run the project's procedures that you can run in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceThread.ProcessRequests call is needed to allow the service manager requests to be processed (starting/pausing/stopping the service) but you don't call it yourself, nor should you override the TServiceThread instance.  The default TServiceThread instance takes care of calling ProcessRequests and also calls the OnStart/OnStop etc handlers of your TService instance.

I normally create a thread in the TService instance OnStart event handler, and let that thread run the service function.

If the service manager stops your service after a short while, it is usually an indication that the ProcessRequests call isn't being called correctly or frequently enough.